# Deriving the variance of a predicted response variable in simple linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, variance, linear-regression

For simple linear regression, I'm trying to derive the variance of the estimator of an individual response variable at some value $X = x^\ast$.

Let $\hat y^\ast$ be the conditional mean response, and $Y^\ast$ be an individual mean response.

It seems like the estimators for BOTH $\hat y^\ast$ and $Y^\ast$ are:

$\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 x^\ast$

Obviously, the variances for these 2 estimators are different, so this is where I'm stuck. If I apply the $Var()$ function to the same estimator, I expect to get the same estimator. However, we know that

- the variance of the conditional mean response is $\sigma^2 (\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x^\ast - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}})$
- the variance of an individual response is $\sigma^2 (1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x^\ast - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}})$

I have read several textbooks about this, and I keep seeing this:

> \begin{align*}
> \mathrm{Var}(Y^*-\hat y^*) & = \mathrm{Var}(Y-\hat y\mid X=x^*)\\
> & =\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X=x^*)+\mathrm{Var}(\hat y\mid X=x^*)-2\mathrm{Cov}(Y,\hat y\mid X=x^*)\\
> & = \sigma^2+\sigma^2\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{(x^*-\bar x)^2}{SXX}\right]-0\\
> & =\sigma^2\left[1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x^*-\bar x)^2}{XXX}\right]
> \end{align*}

This is from Page 37 in Chapter 2.7.4 in "A Modern Approach to Regression with R" by Simon Sheather.

**Where did $V(Y^\ast - \hat y^\ast)?$ come from? Every textbook about this topic seems to just pluck this out of thin air.** If we want the variance of an estimator of $Y^\ast$, then why don't we apply the $\mathrm{Var}()$ function to that estimator?